# How to delete a page from a google doc using app script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I have created a template with several pages. After the template is used, I want to automatically remove any unused page.

This is how it works. I have created a certificate template with 25 pages with placeholders for name and other details. Each page is a certificate. After going through the data, the code below replaces the placeholders with data from the Google Sheets. Once that is completed - I want to remove all the extra pages in the document - for example: if only 5 template pages are modified, I want to remove the remaining 20 template pages from the document.

Any other improvement suggestions are welcome as this is my first App Script.

## Addition to clarify the question:

The script takes data from a Google Sheet which has hundreds of rows of data. For example, if 5 certificates need to be created, the script gets all the data and loop and look for a certain flag (cert_data[i][6] == 1) to identify the rows of data that should be used for the certificate. Once the flag is found, the data in the row are stored in variables and is used to replace the place holders in the template file. Once the data in all flagged rows are replaced - for this example, only 5 template pages are replaced. Hence there will be a balance of 20 pages in the template that has not been used - I want to delete these pages.

```
function createDocument() {

  //Setting ID for database
  var SPREADSHEET_ID = "doc ID"
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SPREADSHEET_ID);
  var worksheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Sheet1");

  var cert_data = worksheet.getDataRange().getValues();  
  //Setting template ID
  var templateId = 'template ID goes here';

  //Make a copy of the template file
  var documentId = DriveApp.getFileById(templateId).makeCopy().getId();


  //Get the document body as a variable
  var body = DocumentApp.openById(documentId).getBody();

  //Foramt date
  var curDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+1", "dd MMMM yyyy")

  var d = 0;


  //Looping through all the data that is in the Google Sheet
  for(var i = 1; i < cert_data.length ; i++){

    var curdata = cert_data[i][6];

    //Checking if the row data is to be used to create certificate
    if (cert_data[i][6] == 1) {
      var training_type = cert_data[i][12];
      var hours = cert_data[i][9];
      var user_name = cert_data[i][1];
      var NIC = cert_data[i][3];
      var date_completed = Utilities.formatDate(cert_data[i][8], "GMT+1", "dd MMMM yyyy");
      var company = cert_data[i][2];
      var cert_number = cert_data[i][0];
      var date_now = curDate;

      //Setting training names

      if (training_type == "01G") {training_type = "Basic First Aid" + String.fromCharCode(10) + "& Automated External" + String.fromCharCode(10) + "Defibrillator Certificate"; var file_name = 'AED Training';}

      if (training_type == "01B") {var file_name = 'Refresher Receipts';}

      d++;

      //Insert the data into the file
      body.replaceText('{training_type' + d + '}', training_type);
      body.replaceText('{hours' + d + '}', hours);
      body.replaceText('{name' + d + '}', user_name);
      body.replaceText('{NIC' + d + '}', NIC);
      body.replaceText('{date_completed' + d + '}', date_completed);
      body.replaceText('{company' + d + '}', company);
      body.replaceText('{cert_numb' + d + '}', cert_number);
      body.replaceText('{date_now' + d + '}', date_now);
    }
  }

    //d is the number of pages used from the template file
    //I want to delete all the balance pages (i.e. 25-d = x)
    //Rename the copied file
    DriveApp.getFileById(documentId).setName(file_name + ' - ' + company);

}
```

Comment: Can you provide the detail information about ``any unused page``? By the way, if you want to achieve this using Google Apps Script, can you provide your current script? By this, it will help users think of your solution.

Comment: Added details - @Tanaike

Comment: Thank you for adding the information. Can I ask you about updated question? 1. Please explain about your script. If your script has issue, also please show it. 2. I couldn't understand about ``only 5 template pages are modified`` using the script. How can we know whether 5 template pages are modified using the script?

Comment: Added further comments to the question and to the code. There is no issue with the script. @Tanaike

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding the information. But unfortunately, I cannot image the vision about your situation, yet. So I couldn't think of about your solution now. When I could completely understand your situation, I would like to think of your solution. I apologize for this situation and my poor English skill.

Comment: In summary, I want to know how to delete a page from a Google Doc using app script. @Tanaike

Comment: Thank you for replying. In your document, each page is separated by the pagebreak? In the current stage, there are no methods for managing the page of Document. So if you want to remove several pages under this situation, it is required to use the pagebreak. How about this?

Comment: Yes, there are page breaks - each template is in a separate page. Is it going to be easier to solve the problem now? I really appreciate the help you've extended so far. Await your answer. @Tanaike

Comment: Thank you for replying. When the Google Document is separated by the page breaks and you want to delete several pages with the page breaks from the last page in order, it can be achieved by the script. Before I think of an answer, I have 3 questions. 1. How do you decide the number of pages you want to delete? 2. What is the relationship between deleting pages and your script in your question? 3. Can you provide a sample Document that you want to delete the pages? At first, I would like to correctly understand about your question. I apologize for taking your time.

Comment: To answer your questions: (1) I decide the number of pages to be deleted based on a formula: 25 - d = number_of_pages_to_delete (see my code for the variable d). (2)  See answer for number 1. (3) Here is how the template would look like, with 25 pages https://docs.google.com/document/d/17GBzJH-ZH666galxLRhp-8RJBW9HIb0r1HxFdOE0ZJY/edit?usp=sharing Thank you very much for the support - appreciate it very much. Please let me know if you have any further questions. @Tanaike

Comment: Thank you for replying and providing a sample Document. From them, I proposed a sample script for deleting pages as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Each page of your Google Document is separated by the page breaks.
- You want to delete several pages of Google Document from the last page in order.
- Number of pages you want to delete is decided by your script.

If my understanding is correct, how about this sample script? The flow of this script is as follows.

#### Flow:

1. Retrieve paragraphs in the body of Document.
2. Retrieve elements in each paragraph. The page break is included in the paragraph.
3. Delete elements from last page in order.
4. When the number of page breaks is the same with `deletePages`, the script is stopped.

By this flow, several pages can be deleted from the last page in order.

#### Sample script:

Please copy&paste the following script and set the variables of `deletePages` and `id`. Then, run the script.

```
function myFunction() {
  var deletePages = 3;
  var id = "### documentId ###";

  var paragraph = DocumentApp.openById(id)
    .getBody()
    .getParagraphs();
  var counter = 0;
  for (var i = paragraph.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    for (var j = 0; j < paragraph[i].getNumChildren(); j++)
      if (
        paragraph[i].getChild(j).getType() == DocumentApp.ElementType.PAGE_BREAK
      )
        counter++;
    if (counter < deletePages)
      paragraph[i].clear();
    else if (counter == deletePages){
      paragraph[i].getChild(paragraph[i].getNumChildren() - 1).removeFromParent();
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

#### Note:

- If you want to delete 5 pages from the last page, please set `var deletePages = 5`.
- Also you can use this function like `myFunction(deletePages)` as a method. At that time, please remove `var deletePages = 3;`.
- You can also use `DocumentApp.getActiveDocument()` instead of `DocumentApp.openById(id)`.
- From [@derekantrican's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56116732/how-to-delete-a-page-from-a-google-doc-using-app-script/56177627?noredirect=1#comment118886369_56177627), I updated the sample script.

#### References:

- [getParagraphs()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#getparagraphs)
- [getChild()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/paragraph#getchildchildindex)
- [clear()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/paragraph#clear)

Comment: Thank you so much for the sample script - appreciate it very much. I do not know how to make your answer the accepted answer! @Tanaike

Comment: @m mustho Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. I could also study from your question. Thank you, too.

Comment: This seems to have an issue where it clears the last paragraph. For instance, if I put "This is page #" on 5 different pages, then run this with `deletePages = 3`, I will end up with 2 pages, but with text only on the first page (ie "This is page 2" on the second page will be gone)

Comment: @derekantrican Thank you for your comment. But I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot image your situation from your comment. So can you provide the detail of your comment? By this, I would like to try to understand about your comment.

Comment: I have made a comment with a suggestion on your gist: https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/6d33c3ce00cd46e45d3551a587b2ae17

Comment: @derekantrican Thank you for replying. I could confirm your sample script. I updated both scripts. Thank you so much.